# TinyMCE: packaging all the files instead of dynamically loading them... possible?

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to get TinyMCE to work. I've tried it using the normal method of including tiny_mce.js and then using tinymce.init(...) and it works. I then tried tiny_mce.gzip.js + php compressor and it worked but it was really slow.

Now I already package up my CSS and JS files into one of each with all my files concatenated together. In the case of Javascript they're also minified.

In both cases they're versioned with a timestamp of one of the files so I have URLs like:

/script/script.1233454569.js

which redirects to a PHP file that either serves a cached version or builds the cached version (if necessary) and serves it. It adds expires headers and does gzip compression and basically works well.

I want to fit tiny mce into this mechanism but it's proving painful. Order seems to matter. Currently I have:

- tiny_mce.js
- myscript.js
- default_editor.js (from the simple theme)
- en.js (ditto)

but it's coming up with "u is undefined" for which I could find no suitable answer on google. This is really irritating. Has anyone any experience with this?

Are any other editors more suitable for packaging like I described above rather than forcing their own schemes on you (which annoys me no end)?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do the exact same thing and spent far too much time trying. In the end, I settled on using the GZip compressor provided by TinyMCE and concentrated on combining the CSS files and images for what I needed. The problem is that TinyMCE is massive, it dynamically loads the files it needs, and it doesn't make use of an existing JavaScript library, so it ends up replicating a lot of the same code if you are already using any sort of library. [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) was the only other editor I felt had the same features and browser compatibility, but it didn't look like it was going to be any easier in terms of integrating into my caching scheme (which sounds similar to yours) and I think the licensing made it a non-choice for me. You can look at a [list](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/WebEditors) of editors available here, but those were the two I felt were the best from that list. In the end, I decided to go with TinyMCE and added making a WYSIWYG editor for MooTools onto my to-do list since that's the JavaScript framework I most often use.

If you were to hack at it, I would suggest figuring out every script that your specific implementation of TinyMCE needs, combine them in order, and then isolate and comment out the code that loads each file. If you're brave, you could then try [packing](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) the combined file as well. If you do get it to work, I'd love to know.

Comment: I was basically following the logic (or trying to) of the gzip compression method to get the right list of files in the right order. I must still be missing something though. It's irritating. I hate it when something is too inflexible to be just simply statically preloaded.

Comment: I tried that too. Between that and the code replication, I decided that my eventual solution would be writing my own. As another option, though, you might want to look into the editor Wordpress uses. It *might* be TinyMCE, but it's pretty fast.

Comment: You might also want to try looking in each file that the gzip file calls to see if they load any additional files (which I suspect they do). Specifically, in the tiny_mce_src.js file, do a find search for "file:", which will lead to a series of comments that might indicate the files called.

Comment: On second look, those comments might not be what I thought they were, they could just be how he breaks it up.

Comment: I went one step further after this and analyzed the Apache access logs to see what was getting called but it seems you can't simply package the lot. It looks like some initialization/ordering is important before loading themes, for example.  Irritating.

Comment: I haven't actually signed up for the TinyMCE forum and asked because it seems the moderator over there really isn't helpful to a lot of different questions, but that might be an option as well. If *they* don't know what order the files are called, well...

Comment: What I've gathered though is that its not just the order but its the timing like the tinymce object has to do a certain amount of initialization before it calls default_editor.js etc or it just dies since those scripts must be relying on certain things being done already.

Comment: I found this thread explaining their process a little, but it doesn't offer much in the way of help: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=10777 However, this thread might be more useful: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=4937

Answer (score 3):

I've also tried concatenating TinyMCE into one minimised script, here's what I did to get it to work:

in `tiny_mce_src.js` change this line...

```
if (n.src && /tiny_mce(|_dev|_src|_gzip|_jquery|_prototype).js/.test(n.src)) {
```

to be either...

```
if (n.src && /YourFullScriptName.js/.test(n.src)) {
```

or even just a part of the script name...

```
if (n.src && /ullScriptNa/.test(n.src)) {
```

It's that line which works out the baseUrl so it can load all the other files that TinyMCE needs. The thing is, because of the license we can't do this. I did have some hope by adding this before the concatenated tiny_mce.js file...

```
var tinyMCEPreInit = {base : 'tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/'};
```

following [Spocke's advice](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=29347#p29347), but I can't seem to get that to work either. The only other thing I can think of, since we're using Prototype, is to dynamically load either the tiny`_`mce.js or the tiny`_`mce`_`**gzip**.js script, then initialize the text area(s) we want from there. But I'm far from finished getting that to work.

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

DJDaveMark

Comment: `var tinyMCEPreInit` may have to be `window.tinyMCEPreInit`

Comment: var tinyMCEPreInit = {base : 'tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/', suffix: '.min', query: ''}; This works for me..

Answer (score 0):

I started up the Gzip Compressor and linked myself with Fiddler in the Rendering Process.

Basically this what arrived in the Browser i catched up and packed it in an own file.

Dirty but working